# Is it possible for a query-replace-regexp to replace the value with a computed value?

Tags: query-replace-regexp

I want to convert the timestamps in a `.zsh_history` file to their readable equivalents.

Does `query-replace-regex` or some other function provide the ability to replace the match with the value of a function like something like `(format-time-string (match 1))`?

```
: 1568128379:0;cp -a ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc
: 1568128381:0;exit
```

**UPDATE:**

See my solution to this particular problem - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/79254/15477

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *Yes*. `C-h f query-replace-regexp` says:

> In interactive calls, the replacement text can contain ‘\,’
> followed by a Lisp expression.  Each
> replacement evaluates that expression to compute the replacement
> string.  Inside of that expression, ‘\&’ is a string denoting the
> whole match as a string, ‘\N’ for a partial match, ‘\#&’ and ‘\#N’
> for the whole or a partial match converted to a number with
> ‘string-to-number’, and ‘\#’ itself for the number of replacements
> done so far (starting with zero).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for my `.zsh_history` example:

The search string:  `\(: \)\([0-9]\{10\}\)\(:0;\)`

The replacement string: `\,(concat (format "%6d " (line-number-at-pos)) (rgx-get-time-string (match-string 2)) "  "))`

A helper function for the unix time string. More of the functionality in the replacement string can be included if preferred.

```
    (defun rgx-get-time-string (unixtimestr)
     (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" (string-to-number unixtimestr))
      )
```

`(match-string 2)` is an alternate expression for the back reference for the second string `\2`.

[match-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html)