# Am I using "replace-regexp-in-string" the right way?

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace-regexp, replace-regexp-in-string

I want to view `~/.zsh_history` files the way they are displayed by the `history` command with raw unixtimestamps converted to properly formatted dates.

```
: 1568128379:0;cp -a ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc
: 1568128381:0;exit
```

So a command like `readhist.sh.el < ~/.zsh_history` on the lines above would produce output like

```
1 2023-10-21 cp -a ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc
2 2023-10-21 exit
```

The first part was to get it to work in the editor which I solved in the link - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/79254/15477.

In the editor

the search string is:  `\(: \)\([0-9]\{10\}\)\(:0;\)`

the replacement string: `\,(concat (format "%6d " 9999) (rgx-get-time-string (match-string 2)) "  "))`

with `rgx-get-time-string` being a function to convert the unixtimestamp correctly.

```
(defun rgx-get-time-string (unixtimestr)
  (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" (string-to-number unixtimestr)))
```

My attempt to convert to a script results  the replacement inserted literally rather than computed.

The `9999` in the `concat` command is a place holder I will replace with an appropriate expression later.later.

```
!/usr/local/bin/emacs --script
;;-*- mode: emacs-lisp;-*-
```

```lisp
    (defun process (histline)
      "return the usual string"
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(: \\)\\([0-9]\\{10\\}\\)\\(:0;\\)"
                                "\,(concat (format \"%6d \"
                                9999)
      (rgx-get-time-string (match-string 2)) \" \"))" histline))
    
    (defun rgx-get-time-string (unixtimestr)
      (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" (string-to-number unixtimestr)))
    
    (condition-case nil
        (let (line)
           (while (setq line (read-from-minibuffer ""))
            ;;(princ line)
            (princ (process line))
            (princ "\n")))
      (error nil))
```

Comment: *"scripting the solution"* - The solution to what question/problem? and *"it doesn't"* [work] - What doesn't work? What does *doesn't work* mean here? The question isn't clear.

Comment: The question needs to stand on its own. If something important needs to be added from some other question/answer, then include that here.

Comment: @Drew The first problem was I had to double the slashes in the regular expression. Now the problem is the `\,` syntax used in `replace-regexp` when the replacement is a lisp expression doesn't seem to work with `replace-regexp-in-string`

Comment: The `\,` syntax in `replace-regexp` only works when you call it interactively. There is no such facility for `replace-regexp-in-string` (it's not an interactive function, i.e. a command) but you can use a function, instead of a string, as the replacement. `C-h f replace-regexp-in-string` is, as always, your friend.

Comment: @NickD It looks like the replacement function has to apply the regex to the passed string again to a function that returns a list of the matched groups for it be useful. Is there a function for that?

Comment: You really need to edit it to specify exactly what your question is. Comments could end up getting deleted, in which case the question would be unclear.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, **ask Emacs**. Use `C-h f` to look up the help for the function `replace-regexp-in-string`. You’ll get something like this:

```
replace-regexp-in-string is a byte-compiled function defined in subr.el.gz.

Signature
(replace-regexp-in-string REGEXP REP STRING &optional FIXEDCASE LITERAL SUBEXP START)

Documentation
Replace all matches for REGEXP with REP in STRING.

Return a new string containing the replacements.

Optional arguments FIXEDCASE, LITERAL and SUBEXP [blah blah blah…].

REP is either a string used as the NEWTEXT arg of replace-match or a
function.  If it is a function, it is called with the actual text of each
match, and its value is used as the replacement text.  When REP is called,
the match data are the result of matching REGEXP against a substring
of STRING, the same substring that is the actual text of the match which
is passed to REP as its argument.

[…]
```

See the bit at the end about the REP argument? It can be a function, like this:

```lisp
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(: \\)\\([0-9]\\{10\\}\\)\\(:0;\\)"
                          (lambda (match)
                            (concat (format "%6d " 9999)
                                    (rgx-get-time-string match)
                                    " "))
                          histline)
```

Incidentally, if that 9999 is supposed to become a line number, then you could just pipe the output through `cat -n` instead. That will save you some work.